# Python Tkinter Menu widget:

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, widget

I've been trying to learn Tkinter and i've stumbled upon the below code while looking up Menu widget.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


top = Tk()

mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="condiments", relief=RAISED )
mb.grid()
mb.menu =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0)
mb["menu"] =  mb.menu

mayoVar = IntVar()
ketchVar = IntVar()

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="mayo",
                          variable=mayoVar )
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="ketchup",
                          variable=ketchVar )

mb.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Now i undertand the purpose of code but am having  a hard time figuring out what the below line of code is for.

```
mb["menu"] =  mb.menu
```

Comment: you don't have to put spaces around `(` and `)` - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: remove line `mb["menu"]` ans see what's happen.

Comment: @PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code – furas the code functions i just have an issue with understanding the line    "mb["menu"] =  mb.menu"

Comment: line `mb["menu"] = Menu() ` assigns `Menu ID` to `Menubutton` - so Menubutton knows what to display. `mb.menu = ... `doesn't assign `Menu` to  `Menubutton` and you can use any other variable ie. `submenu` instead of `mb.menu`

Comment: It is easier to answer for problem if code is correctly formated.

Comment: @furas yep tried it the drop down dosent work

Comment: BTW: it is place for comments which don't have to resolve your problem but they can show other problems.

Answer (score 1):

`mb["menu"] = Menu()` assigns `Menu ID` to `Menubutton` - so `Menubutton` knows what to display.

`mb.menu = ...` doesn't assign `Menu` to `Menubutton` and you can use any other variable ie. `mb.hello_world` or `submenu` instead of `mb.menu` like in example below

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

mb = tk.Menubutton(root, text="condiments", relief=tk.RAISED)
mb.grid()

submenu = tk.Menu(mb, tearoff=0)

mayo_var = tk.IntVar()
ketch_var = tk.IntVar()

submenu.add_checkbutton(label="mayo", variable=mayo_var)
submenu.add_checkbutton(label="ketchup", variable=ketch_var)

mb['menu'] = submenu

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Further note that, `mb['menu'] = submenu` is practically singular option configuration equivalent of `mb.config(menu=submenu)` and `mb.configure(menu=submenu)`.